# How can I get the names a files inside a directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Good day all

I have a test path name ""C:\test". There are the following folders in my directory:

```
importantStuff
UselessStuff
TopSecret
```

My question is this: How can I have Visual Basic return these exact names if I input the path "C:\test"? I have tried to use Directory.GetFiles(path), but it returns the path of those folders, and not their names. I'm stuck with this.

Just as a note: I am trying to port a program I wrote in python to vb.net. In python there is the function os.listdir(path). I essentialy want the vb.net equivalent of this

Comment: You're not always going to be able to find a single method call to do exactly what you want. Sometimes you have to use your brain and put a few method calls together to achieve it in steps. You already know how to get the paths of the files so now you need to work out how to get the name from the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim direct As New DirectoryInfo(".\")
        'Get the files based on .txt extension
Dim files As FileInfo() = direct.GetFiles("*.*")

        'loop through each files and add it to Listbox control
For Each file As FileInfo In files 
  ComboBox.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name))
Next
```